# How to compare competing players with different number of games?

Tags: statistics, game-theory

I hope this is the right place, because the basic problem is mathematical.

Regularly my flatmates and I play a card game. But we are playing this in different player constellations and not always with the same number of players.
But I want to compare how good or bad a player was and to choose a winner e.g. after X games.

What would be a good and fair way to calculate this?

My base idea was to weight the victories with the relative number of games they played.
But I didn't come up with a good solution.

Is there an existing formula or a similar problem already solved?

Comment: "But I didn't come up with a good solution."  How did you know it was not good?

Comment: I didn't like it :D going to edit my post later, to add my approaches and explain them

Comment: "But we are playing this in different player constellations." Can you please explain to me what that means?

Comment: We are 6 players in total. We play with 3 to 4 players per game. Which players participate is "random".

Comment: Does just one person win each game?

Comment: Yes, but a draw is also possible. But only ending up as winner is important. So a second place is not relevant. And a draw is not as good as a win.

Comment: Well, I don't suppose there is going to be any sort of unique comparison.  Look at the NFL rankings, for instance.  Straight record first, but then a fairly bizarre chain of tests used to break ties.  You need to decide what properties you want and even after that there will almost certainly need to be "tie-breakers" of some sort or other.

Comment: As the number of players varies, you will at least need to sort out how to weight games with different numbers.  Suppose, for example, that this is a game of pure chance (drawing high card from a deck, say).  Then just tallying wins will grossly favor the player who only plays with small numbers of opponents.  That is a purely numerical bias and in no way reflects upon the caliber of the players.

Comment: The usual starting point is the [Elo rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system)